# Convert date with Time Zone formats in R

Tags: r, date, date-formatting

I have my dates in the following format :- `Wed Apr 25 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Standard Time)` or `43167` or `Fri May 18 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)` all mixed in 1 column. What would be the easiest way to convert all of these in a simple `YYYY-mm-dd (2018-04-13)` format? Here is the column:

```
dates <- c('Fri May 18 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
'43203',
'Wed Apr 25 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Standard Time)',
'43167','43201',
'Fri May 18 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
'Tue May 29 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Standard Time)',
'Tue May 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
'Fri May 25 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Standard Time)',
'Fri Apr 06 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)','43173')
```

Expected format:`2018-05-18, 2018-04-13, 2018-04-25, ...`

Comment: Please provide some reproducible sample data. You probably need to identify each different format and deal individually with it, though parsers like `lubridate` can help to a great extent

Comment: can you give ten rows of the column that is mixed? and the expected results?

Comment: does `dplyr::coalesce(as.Date(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(dates)),"1900-01-01"),as.Date(strptime(dates,"%a %b %d %Y")))` give you the expected output?

Comment: @Onyambu This is a good solution too. Please post it as an answer. I will upvote it. Unfortunately I cannot mark 2 answers as accepted. Thank you for the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe similar questions have been asked several times before. However, there 
is a crucial point which needs special attention:

*What is the `origin` for the dates given as integer (or as character string which can be converted to integer to be exact)?*

If the data is imported from the Windows version of Excel, `origin = "1899-12-30"` has to be used. For details, see the *Example* section in `help(as.Date)` and [the Other Applications section of the R Help Desk article by Gabor Grothendieck and Thomas Petzoldt](http://r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf).

For conversion of the date time strings, the `mdy_hms()` function from the `lubridate` package is used. In addition, I am using `data.table` syntax for its conciseness:

```
library(data.table)
data.table(dates)[!dates %like% "^\\d+$", new_date := as.Date(lubridate::mdy_hms(dates))][
  is.na(new_date), new_date := as.Date(as.integer(dates), origin = "1899-12-30")][]
```

> ```
>                                                         dates   new_date
>  1:                   Fri May 18 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT) 2018-05-18
>  2:                                                     43203 2018-04-13
>  3: Wed Apr 25 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Standard Time) 2018-04-25
>  4:                                                     43167 2018-03-08
>  5:                                                     43201 2018-04-11
>  6:                   Fri May 18 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT) 2018-05-18
>  7: Tue May 29 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Standard Time) 2018-05-29
>  8:                   Tue May 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT) 2018-05-01
>  9: Fri May 25 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Standard Time) 2018-05-25
> 10:                   Fri Apr 06 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT) 2018-04-06
> 11:                                                     43173 2018-03-14
> ```

Apparently, the assumption to choose the origin which belongs to the Windows version of Excel seems to hold.

If only a vector of `Date` values is required:

```
data.table(dates)[!dates %like% "^\\d+$", new_date := as.Date(lubridate::mdy_hms(dates))][
  is.na(new_date), new_date := as.Date(as.integer(dates), origin = "1899-12-30")][, new_date]
```

> ```
>  [1] "2018-05-18" "2018-04-13" "2018-04-25" "2018-03-08" "2018-04-11" "2018-05-18"
>  [7] "2018-05-29" "2018-05-01" "2018-05-25" "2018-04-06" "2018-03-14"
> ```

Comment: Awesome!! Works like a charm. Great short piece of code. Need to learn lubridate.